# How to evaluate jenkins pipeline status from another pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following pipeline setup:

- Pipeline A starts at 10am and contains multiple subpipelines (A1, A2, A3,...)
- Pipeline B starts at 12am.

In pipeline B i want to check the status of some subpipelines. For example if A1 &&

```
if (A1.equals("Success") && A2.equals("Success")) {
  start jobX
}
```

Note that during this evaluation Pipeline A is still running. Is there a way to achive this?

Answer (score 0):

By 'subpipelines' do you mean that they are building(calling/initiating) a different job?